# How to add System.Windows.Interactivity to project?

Tags: c#, wpf

My project missing `System.Windows.Interactivity`. Google says that I have to install Expression Blend, but on my other computer I have this library and I don't have Expression Blend installed. So there should be another way to obtain `System.Windows.Interactivity`? What should I do? (right now i don't have another computer so I can not just copy this library :)

Comment: For visual studio 2019 check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701484/3088349

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The official package for behaviors is [**`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/).

It used to be in the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) (deprecated).
See [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240223/546730) for more details if you need to migrate.

Comment: Is that version compatible with .Net Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: @VansFannel: No idea, haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Not compatible with 4.6 !

Comment: @alerya: It should not be too hard to find the most current version of that library.

Comment: It's very sad and makes me mad. I am sadly using code behind for that reason. Shame on MS.

Comment: @alerya: 1. You can completely write the behaviour of that SDK yourself if you really want to. 2. Have you tried to the nu-get package?

Comment: I know this is obvious to some of you but you need to reference is:`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"` not:
 `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` like in every other example I've seen.

Comment: @YosefBernal no its not obvious for beginners. This helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 270):

Although this issue is quite old, i think this is relevant news / the most recent answer: Microsoft open-sourced XAML Behaviours and posted a blog post how to update to this version: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

To save you a click, this is the main steps to migrate:

1. Remove reference to “Microsoft.Expression.Interactions” and “System.Windows.Interactivity”
2. Install the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package.
3. XAML files – replace  the xmlns namespaces http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity and http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions with http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors
4. C# files – replace the usings in c# files “Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity” and “Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions” with “Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors”

Comment: This is--now--absolutely the correct answer. I'm so glad Microsoft has finally done this. Thanks for posting it. I'm not sure how I missed the blog entry. There should be a newsletter for "Cool, new Microsoft NuGet packages."

Comment: If Stackoverflow has emotions, I would use a hart for your answer

Comment: Should be the selected answer as of 2019. Thanks for taking time to add this important update.

Comment: Worked for me. I updated solution from 2015 on VS2019. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, if you're using any of the shapes in http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing, you can use [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Expression.Drawing/) - no code changes are required.

Comment: [Prism.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/) package still has `System.Windows.Interactivity`. If you use the prism framework, you don't need to use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`.

Comment: After installing Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf, it works on my local Visual Studio 2019 but it fails on build agent. Nuget restore step is there before the build step. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sundeep Have you had any luck with build agent? Have the same issue and no solution is working for me

Comment: @n0ne: Yes, if it is your build server, make sure you update you have 2019 on your build server.

Comment: Probably it is easy to see but replace also ei with i inside EventTrigger if you use CallMethodAction.

Comment: I followed this guide and had the error "Unknown build error, Cannot resolve dependency [...] , because it has been preloaded. When using the reflection-only APIs, dependant assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event." after installing version 1.1.39 of the nuget package. Removing the dependency Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Design solved the issue. Solution found with https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740734/18783212.

Comment: Thank you - this helped a lot. Note for future readers: Don't be fooled by intellisense and on-the-fly error messages. It reports that it cannot find the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors assembly. Just rebuild the solution!

Comment: @DanielElkington Looks like that nuget is no longer available. Any other options?

Answer (score 64):

There is a new NuGet package that contains the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll that is compatible with:

- WPF 4.0, 4.5
- Silverligt 4.0, 5.0
- Windows Phone 7.1, 8.0
- Windows Store 8, 8.1

To install Expression.Blend.Sdk, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package Expression.Blend.Sdk
```

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/

Comment: Note that this package is not an official Microsoft distribution

Comment: If you have MVVM Light already installed, it will introduce a clashing version of `System.Windows.Interactivity`. To resolve, see my answer above.

Comment: If you are using Caliburn.Micro (v 2), then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way might be to get it from NuGet:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

Comment: Note that this package is not an official Microsoft distribution

Answer (score 22):

With **Blend for Visual Studio**, which is included in Visual Studio starting with version 2013, you can find the DLL in the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries
```

You will have to add the reference to the `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` yourself though, unless you use Blend for Visual Studio with an existing project to add functionality that makes use of the Interactivity namespace. In that case, Blend will add the reference automatically.

Comment: This helped this fix my project. With Visual Studio 2017, we have to go in Visual Studio Installer and find it in the Individual Components (SDK category).

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes, when you add a new library, in introduces a clashing version of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

For example, the NuGet package `MVVM light` might require v4.2 of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`, but the NuGet package `Rx-XAML` might require v4.5 of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`. This will prevent the the project from working, because no matter which version of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` you include, one of the libraries will refuse to compile.

To fix, add an Assembly Binding Redirect by editing your `app.config` to look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity"
                          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestKey" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Don't worry about changing the `PublicKeyToken`, that's constant across all versions, as it depends on the name of the .dll, not the version.

Ensure that you match the `newVersion` in your `appConfig` to the actual version that you end up pointing at:

[image]

Comment: You did the exact same post here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514027/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-windows-interactivity
Multiple points :)

Answer (score 16):

Alternative solution is to **modify** your current Visual Studio installation in the Visual Studio Installer 
 <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe`
adding the `Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET` 'Individual component' under 'SDKs, libraries, and frameworks':

[image]
after adding this component `System.Windows.Interactivity` should appear in its regular location `Add Reference/Assemblies/Extensions`.

---

It appears this would only work for VS2017 or earlier. For later versions, please refer to other answers.

Comment: does not appear for me :(

Comment: does not appear for me either. using VS 2019

Comment: @BarışAkkurt check this answer for visual studio 2019  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701484/3088349

Answer (score 6):

I have had the exact same problem with a solution, that `System.Windows.Interactivity` was required for one of the project in Visual Studio 2019, and I tried to install `Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET` from Visual Studio 2019 Individual components, but it did not exist in it.

**The consequence** of that, I was not able to build the project in my solution with repetitive of following similar error on different XAML parts of the project:

> The tag 'Interaction.Behaviors' does not exist in XML namespace
> 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity'.

[image: Image with all errors]
*The above mentioned errors snapshot example*

**The solution**, the way I solved it, is by installing [Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) from Microsoft.

Thanks to my colleague @felza, mentioned that `System.Windows.Interactivity` requires this sdk, that is suppose to be located in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0
```

In my case it was not installed. I have had this folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs` with out `Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0` folder inside it.

After installing it, all errors disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

It's in MVVM Light, get it from the [MVVM Light Download Page](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Best Solution. Addition: use nuget `Install-Package MvvmLightLibs -Version 5.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

I got it via the Prism.WPF NuGet-Package. (it includes Windows.System.Interactivity)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MVVM Light you have to use the `System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.0` (the NuGet .dll wont work) that you can find under :

`PathToProjectFolder\Software\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.4.1.1\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`

Just add this .dll manually as Reference and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error using Visual Studio 2019:

> **System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:** 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Our project is using packages.config and had NuGet references to `MVVMLightLibs 5.4.1.1` and `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF 2.0.20525`.

Guided by some of the other answers here, I realised the problem was a conflict between the version of the DLL that MVVMLight was using and the one our project was using. The solution was:

- Remove the NuGet reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`.
- Added a Reference to `packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.4.1.1\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.
- Add (in our case, update) a Binding Redirect to app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following two NuGet packages

1.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.wpf

2.Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF

Moreover while installing VS2022 see option to install blend sdk. click on the checkbox while installing.If you have not found that check box then tick the UWP and then you can see that option while installing VS 2022.