# Scroll wpf textblock to end

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

Is there any feature of the `TextBlock` that allows scrolling to the end always?

I've seen a number of examples that do this in the **code behind**,

I want to **keep the principle of MVVM** and not touch the code behind,

I'm looking for a way to do this in `XAML`.

Have one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming your `TextBlock` is nested within a `ScrollViewer`. In this case you are going to have to create an attached property. See this related question:

[How to scroll to the bottom of a ScrollViewer automatically with Xaml and binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370209/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-scrollviewer-automatically-with-xaml-and-bindin)

i.e. create an attached property:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool GetAutoScroll(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoScrollProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoScroll(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoScrollProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScroll", typeof(bool), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(false, AutoScrollPropertyChanged));

    private static void AutoScrollPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer local:Helper.AutoScroll="{Binding BooleanViewModelPropertyThatTriggersScroll}" .../>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in XAML only? This is the simplest way ..?

Comment: @HodayaShalom no, this is not a supported feature of the platform. You will need to write some code!