# Scroll Viewer remains at the last position where I left it last time in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am working on a user control using **MVVM architectural** style and facing an issue while using the **scroll viewer**.
Whenever I open the user control, I find the scroll Viewer at the same position where I left it last time. I want that whenever I open the control I should get the scroll viewer at the top position.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Please help me with any kind of solution.

Comment: At the constructor of your user control call a method/event and set these ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop();
ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();

Comment: Check out this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370209/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-scrollviewer-automatically-with-xaml-and-bindin/8372627#8372627

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to move the scrollviewer postion to top

```
ScrollViewer scroll = //FindyourScrollViewerControlHere

scroll.ScrollToTop();
```

Use the following approach, if you want the scrolling using XAML and binding

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372627/1612065

Comment: Is there any property or some code which we can use in xaml ?