# How to continuously scroll to bottom of scrollviewer MVVM after interruption

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have previously used the Attached Property which was the top response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370209/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-scrollviewer-automatically-with-xaml-and-bindin). I used it on a text block that was an output window for a background process. However I have notice that, when I scroll up inside the scroll viewer, the scroll viewer stops scrolling to the bottom.

I cannot figure out how to ensure that the scroll viewer continues scrolling to the bottom. Please could you suggest reasons why this might be happening or how I might go about rectifying this issue without code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the attached property to listen to changes in the property the `TextBlock`'s `Text` is bound to, so whenever that changes your `ScrollViewer` will scroll to the bottom.

Usage:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" myApp:ScrollViewerAttachedProperties.ScrollToBottomOnChange="{Binding Logs}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Logs}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The attached property:

```
public static class ScrollViewerAttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollToBottomOnChangeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ScrollToBottomOnChange", typeof(object), typeof(ScrollViewerAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(ScrollViewer), OnScrollToBottomOnChangeChanged));

    private static void OnScrollToBottomOnChangeChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var scrollViewer = dependencyObject as ScrollViewer;
        scrollViewer?.ScrollToBottom();
    }

    public static void SetScrollToBottomOnChange(DependencyObject element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ScrollToBottomOnChangeProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetScrollToBottomOnChange(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(ScrollToBottomOnChangeProperty);
    }
}
```