# DataGrid bind command to row select

Tags: wpf, select, data-binding, datagrid, command

I want to execute a command when the user selects a row in a DataGrid.

I see it is possible to  wrap cell contents in buttons (although I don't want the button style) - but I don't want to do it at the cell-level.

I also see it's possible to use behaviours to link a command to an event. But preferably I should not have to resort to behaviors for such a common task.

Is it possible to do this via plain old command databinding?

So: 1) user clicks DataGrid row 2) command on view model is fired.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should use "Interactivity" assembly and `SelectionChanged` event.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Where "i" is namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Also you can write binding to `SelectedItem` property of the DataGrid and in the set accessor you can invoke your command, but the first solution that i presented you above is better.

If you want to invoke command from main view model and pass `SelectedItem` from `DataGrid` you can use `CommadParameter`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When items has own command you can use following code:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Or if elements has own view model that is assigned to it's `DataContext`, you can use following code:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Marking as answer so far because it looks good and is reasonably simple. Thanks! I've also tried SelectedItem but had some issues due to virtualization. In general it appears the DataGrid has some bugs.

Comment: Okay, just tried and this then fires on the top-level view model, not the view model for each element in the DataGrid. I don't suppose I can make it fire directly on the relevant view model? Otherwise I guess I'll use SelectedItem as well.

Comment: @BentRasmussen check my answer again, I added more examples.

Comment: Triple-thumbs-up! You saved me a load of trouble! I had a very ugly back before. Thanks a million!

Comment: @kmatyaszek What would you say it is an advantage of executing a command over Binding SelectedItem to a viewmodel property SelectedObject?

Comment: That namespace reference doesn't appear to be working form me. "The type Interaction was not found", and/or "The name “Interaction” does not exist in the namespace"

Comment: @JonathanTuzman please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project

Answer (score 2):

Be advised that @kmatyaszek's answer is outdated in .NET 5.0 and above, we should use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors` instead of `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`.

So the `i` in the namespace should be:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/) for details.