# DataGrid bind command to cell click

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, triggers

Here's a quick question. I have a DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sections}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ImportName, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Imported" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FoundName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Suggested" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to bind "Suggested" column cells to a command in my VM, so that each time user clicks the cell for editing, my command would execute and show a dialog for the user. I've found an interesting solution to a similar problem described here: [DataGrid bind command to row select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327227/datagrid-bind-command-to-row-select)

I like the fact that it manages this from XAML without any code-behind that attaches to the cell editing event. Unfortunately, I've no idea how to convert it in a way that would allow me to bind command to cells in a specific column, rather than the entire row. Any advice in regards to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeginningEdit` event in the `DataGrid` control to handle this scenario. This event will fires before a row or cell enters edit mode. You can identify the selected column from the EventArgs. 
Example:

```
private void dgName_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Suggested")
            {
                //Do Operation
            }
        }
```

If you are using MVVM pattern, there are options to pass EventArgs to VM. If you are uusing MVVMLight Toolkit, there is an option called `PassEventArgs` and set it to `TRUE`.

In VM,

//Relay Command

```
private RelayCommand<DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs> _cellBeginningEditCommand;
    public RelayCommand<DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs> CellBeginningEditCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cellBeginningEditCommand ?? (_cellBeginningEditCommand = new RelayCommand<DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs>(CellBeginningEditMethod));
        }
    }
```

//Command Handler

```
private void CellBeginningEditMethod(DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs args)
        {
            if(args.Column.Header.ToString() == "Suggested")
            {
                //Do Operation
            }
        }
```