# use of selectedindex in datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, mvvm-light, selectedindex

I'm learning wpf with mvvm light and i'm face an issue.
I've a usercontrol with a datagrid that's loaded with a query.

Now i'd like to add an event on the selectedIndex to retrieve the selected line and after that i'll pass the value to an other user control.

the issue is that my event is never fired.

Here is what i did

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dgUser" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="800" Height="253" >
```

Here is the code of my viewmodel

```
public RelayCommand selectedRow { get; private set; }
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ListUserViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public ListUserViewModel()
    {
        selectedRow = new RelayCommand(() => SelectedRowChange());
        SelectedIndex = 2;
    }

    private void SelectedRowChange()
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

My row is not selected with SelectedXIndex = 2 
and nothing happen when i select an other row

Comment: `SelectedItem` is not an event, it's a property. `SelectionChanged` is the event. Try to use it.

Comment: selectionChanged throw an exception except if i use an EventTrigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind a `Command` on your ViewModel to the `SelectedItem` of your DataGrid and that's not quite how it works.

You want to hook into the `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event and presumably fire your ViewModel's `RelayCommand` at that point.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15327630/140176) for a great explanation on how to do this in XAML.

EDIT:

To pass the `SelectedItem` to your `RelayCommand` as a command parameter, use the following in your XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and ensure that you change your `RelayCommand` to be of the type you wish.

*NOTE: You have not provided what the type of the items you have in your `DataGrid`, so I'll use `object` here.*

```
public RelayCommand<object> selectedRow { get; private set; }
```

You can then rely on the command's parameter being the selected item:

```
public ListUserViewModel()
{
    selectedRow = new RelayCommand(i => SelectedRowChange(i));
    SelectedIndex = 2;
}

private void SelectedRowChange(object selectedItem)
{
    // selectedItem is the item that has just been selected
    // do what you wish with it here
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: thanks i use EventTrigger and my event is fired with messagebox but how can i have the value of the selected row?

Comment: You can pass the `SelectedItem` as a parameter to your `RelayCommand` through the other examples in that post. If this answered your question, please click the green tick on the left.

Comment: Could you explain me how is use commandparameter? and my row is not from a model but with a query.tolist()

Comment: Updated. If you have any further questions please ask another question.

Comment: The command parameter. `RelayCommand<object>`. You need to read more about WPF and MVVM Light if you do not understand this.