# Blur background in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, effects

I am trying to create a blur effect in WPF, but I want to blur the content located behind the control (such as a Grid), I do not intend to blur the contents of the Grid.

I want to do something like this image.

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27447817/815938) is a code sample.

Comment: See my link in the first comment of the above linked question. Despite the OP of that question disregarding my advice, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? The answers given are not satisfactory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for something like this:

[image: blur cherries]

The answer is to use a `BitmapEffect` :

```
<Image Source="http://www.pingminghealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/cherries.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.BitmapEffect>
        <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="20" />
    </Image.BitmapEffect>
</Image>
```

You can find a tutorial about it on msdn: [How to Apply a Blur Effect to a Visual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742795%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, someone is still looking for a solution in 2018, something like this worked for me: [BlurryControls.BlurryUserControl.cs](https://github.com/ConfusedHorse/BlurryControls/blob/master/BlurryControls/Controls/BlurryUserControl.cs)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the solution here, as this answer might get useless if the linked page changes or vanishes

Answer (score -2):

```
<Rectangle>  
    <Rectangle.Effect>  
        <BlurEffect Radius="{DynamicResource BlurRadius}"/>  
    </Rectangle.Effect>  
    <Rectangle.Fill>  
        <VisualBrush  
ViewboxUnits="Absolute"  
Viewbox="{Binding RenderTransform.Children[3],  
        Converter={StaticResource TranslateTransformToRectViewboxVisualBrushConverter},  
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},  
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
        AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"  
    Visual="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundContainer}" Stretch="None">  
            <VisualBrush.Transform>  
                <TranslateTransform X="0" />  
            </VisualBrush.Transform>  
        </VisualBrush>  
    </Rectangle.Fill>  
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: I fail to see how that answers OP's question.

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to make the grid semi transparent but how to add a blur effect to whatever is behind it, this answer only makes it transparent which is the easy part hence my -1.

Comment: go through this link for blurry transparent

Comment: @Dhru'soni The link is dead, could you have the information about it ?  thanks