# How to create a blurred background dialog box using Win2D?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win2d

I'm using Win2D library, I need to know how to show a dialog box that is opaque and shows a blurry transparent background when opened like the windows 10 start menu and notification panel. I've been seeing a lot of example that blurrs an image, but what I really want to do is like a frosted glass dialog box.

An example of what I want to do is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432466/layered-window-with-blur-effect/27447817#27447817), but I need it for windows app not wpf.

Comment: Ho does a frosted background compare to a blurred background? How close have you gotten? Can we see the code? I'd think a blur plus a static mostly transparent image scaled and tiled would probably result in a decent output.

Comment: I think blurred or frosted, for me is basically the same. The idea is to make a control similar to windows 10 start menu or IOS notification drop down. I've been working on Win2D and I've tried to blurr a text inside the canvas control but still have no idea on how I can blur the control underneath my dialog box.

Comment: I think I'm having progress, I can actually render the UI as a bitmap and then blurr that bitmap so that it may look like a background that is blurred. I've used RenderTargetBitmap to get a screenshot (bitmap) of the UI (layout root grid). Then I used that bitmap as the source of my GaussianBlurrEffect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to do this and it worked perfectly. 
http://metulev.com/render-xaml-to-image-and-more/

Update: 
I created a xaml behavior that can make a panel or a border blurred. 
https://github.com/lancecontreras/FrostedGlassBehavior