# Creating C# WPF Form with Transparent Blurred Background

Tags: c#, wpf, background, transparent

i'm going to create a C# WPF Form with Transparent blurred Background.

I want this form show In front of my desktop and any application behind is blurred

Here is my example created with photoshop:
[image]

Additional Question: Can I do it on C# Windows Form, or Have a library can help me do it ???
Thank you very much.

Comment: WPF and Windows Forms are different technologies. Which one are you trying to implement, really?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815278/blur-the-background-of-the-wpf-container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432466/layered-window-with-blur-effect/27447817#27447817

Comment: Create a transparent window in WPF and add you photoshop image as background

Comment: i want my application has transparent background, which i can see another windows behind, but it should be blur, not to be a fixed background image

Answer (score 0):

In WPF Window Form, it's belong to your OS Window:

- Windows 10: Solution using `SetWindowCompositionAttribute`
- Windows 8: No solution
- Windows 7: You can continue to use `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`