# WPF difference between 'interactivity' and 'interactions'

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can anybody please explain the difference between interactivity and interactions?

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ia="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Some goals, lets say Triggers, can be achieved with any of those, in a different manner. For modern WPF MVVM applications that use Prism 5.0 - is it acceptable to use both? I mainly use 'interactivity', but when it comes to drag/drop and Mouse events - 'interactivity' is killing me, I grab 'interactions'. What would real MVVM gurus say?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late as some years have passed, but maybe for someone it'll still be of some value:

As for 2020 this **difference is unimportant as both of them were replaced by Behaviours.**

[Link to NuGet package to Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/).

For more information refer to [Jan answer in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project/56240223#56240223).