# The imported project C:\...\v4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets" was not found

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I was developing my WPF projects using Visual Studio 2013 in my old window 7. But when I installed new Windows 10 and also Visual Studio 2017 and tried to open my project; my project fail to load and got this error message:

> the imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets"
>   was not found. Also, tried to fiend
>   "Microsoft\Expression\Blend.NetFramework\v.4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets
>   in the fallback searchpath(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) -
>   "C:\Progam Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in
>   "C:\Users\AdminPC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_51bebed7\devenv.exe.config"
>   . Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct , and
>   that the file exists on the disk in one of the search paths.
>   C:\Users\AdminPC\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyCustomMessages\MyCustomMessages.csproj

I Searched for some solutions I found I have to install BlendWPFSDKv4_en.msi Version 4, but still doesn't help also there is no BlendWPFSDKv4_en.msi version 4.5. What Should I do, Shall I install VS 2013 in order to fix this issue?

[image: Unloaded Project cuz of Blend v4.5]

Comment: Ensure that Blend is installed and that you selected the .NET Framework 4.5 SDK on the Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Camilo Terevinto, Thanks for the reply. I did want you tell me but still the issue stands

Comment: No, install blend for your current version of visual studio.

Comment: Leo Liu-MSFT, Thanks for replying my issue. I can't find ...\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets. Not even from another device who has VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem by installing VS2015 in the same machine that has VS2017 and now the project works fine in VS2017.

Answer (score 5):

> The imported project C:\…\v4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets" was not found

Found it. You should launch the Visual Studio Installer from the start menu, switch to the "**Individual components**" page, under the "**SDKs, libraries, and frameworks**" heading, find the "**Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET**" and install it:

[image]

After the installation is complete, you will find it under the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.5
```

Certified:[Visual Studio 2017 - What happened to Expression interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047840/visual-studio-2017-what-happened-to-expression-interactions)

Hope this helps.

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer!** you saved my VS project! Thank you!

Comment: In the current setup of VS 2019 this "Blend for Visual Studio SDK" entry is removed ... --> download and install the Blend SDK from Microsoft separately as mentioned in an other answer

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the reference to blend;

1. With VS 2019 - Right click on the (unloaded/load failed) project.
2. Select - edit your `*****.csproj` file.
3. At the bottom of the file, remove the following line

   ```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WPF.targets" />
   ```
4. Save, Reload the project & happiness.

Answer (score 2):

I had solved the problem by installing

Install Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4,

without install an older version of VS