# Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET in VS2019

Tags: blend, interaction, visual-studio-2019

I need Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET in Visual Studio 2019 to use Interaction Triggers. In VS2017 it was in Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET as you can see here:
[Visual Studio 2017 - What happened to Expression interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047840/visual-studio-2017-what-happened-to-expression-interactions)

Where is this option in VS2019?

Thank you

UPDATE: what I really need is System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, both of them version 4.5.0.0

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/535255/how-to-install-blend-sdk-in-visual-studio-2019.html

Comment: @HansPassant I think this solution is not valid for me, because I need System.Windows.Interactivity 4.5.0.0 (I still use prism 5.0)

Comment: Lol, I authored the 2017 question you linked and just found yours after upgrading to 2019 and being the same boat.  I really wish every new version of VS wouldn't make breaking changes to our projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try these nuget packages:

[Microsoft.Expression.Blend.SDK.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Expression.Blend.SDK.WPF): Microsofts expression blend SDK for WPF (4.0)

[Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend): Micosoft Expression Blend SDK for 4.5

[Expression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk): Contains System.Windows.Interactivity (4.0, 4.5)

They all wrap Blend SDK dlls into a nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

As for 2020 both of them were replaced by Behaviours as mentioned in [Jan's answer in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project/56240223#56240223).

[Link to NuGet package to Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/).

If you want to use them you have to:

1. Remove reference to “Microsoft.Expression.Interactions” and “System.Windows.Interactivity”
2. Install the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package.
3. XAML files – replace xmlns namespaces of interactions and interactivity with behaviour.
4. C# file - replace usings of interactions with behaviours.

Comment: So I have a XAML entry for xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" and xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" in VS2019. Is my SWI stuff working because I have the blend? Also, could you add a simple example of the XAML changes - before and after - to your post?