# Where can I download v4.5 of the expression blend SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, expression-blend

On my dev machine with vs2017 installed I have

[image]

but on the CI server with only the MSBuildTools installed. No Visual Studio I have tried downloading the blend SDK but I can only find v4.0

https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Can I get v4.5 without installed visual studio?

Comment: If you just need the SDK installed for references in code, you can use the Nuget package instead.  Any build servers should be able to automatically restore Nuget packages during build, so you won't have to worry about it being installed. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the packages on the build server? I don't want to add these nuget package to every solution.

Comment: Just a note in case it applies to you, the behaviors/interactivity was open sourced and moved to a new NuGet package: [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240223/1364358) (includes details of how to migrate, just needs a couple of tweaks).