# How to read TextBox focus from ViewModel - MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, mvvm-light

I have two textBoxes and in my ViewModel I would like to be able to keep track of which box is currently in focus.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Text Box 1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="Text Box 2"/>
```

How can I read/identify which textBox is currently in focus from my ViewModel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways how you can achieve this, some of them:

**1) Use behavior:**

- You need [System.Windows.Interactivity.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project)
- Behavior (setting `IsFocused` property will not make element focused, you need slightly extend behavior in order to achieve this)

  ```
  public class FocusChangedBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register(
         nameof(IsFocused),
         typeof(bool),
         typeof(FocusChangedBehavior),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), 
              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

      public bool IsFocused
      {
          get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty); }
          set { this.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value); }
      }

      /// <inheritdoc />
      protected override void OnAttached()
      {
          this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus += this.AssociatedObjectFocused;
          this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus += this.AssociatedObjectUnfocused;
      }

      /// <inheritdoc />
      protected override void OnDetaching()
      {
          this.AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= this.AssociatedObjectFocused;
          this.AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= this.AssociatedObjectUnfocused;
      }

      private void AssociatedObjectFocused(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.IsFocused = true;
      }

      private void AssociatedObjectUnfocused(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.IsFocused = false;
      }
  }
  ```
- In XAML you bind `IsFocused` to property in ViewModel. 
   
  `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

  ```
  <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Text Box 1">
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <local:FocusChangedBehavior IsFocused="{Binding IsFocusedTxt1}" />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </TextBox>

  <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="Text Box 2">
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <local:FocusChangedBehavior IsFocused="{Binding IsFocusedTxt2}" />
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </TextBox>
  ```
- Finally in View-Model create properties

  ```
  public bool IsFocusedTxt1 { get; set; }

  public bool IsFocusedTxt2 { get; set; }
  ```

**2) Alternatively you could you use `EventTrigger` in the XAML**

- You need [System.Windows.Interactivity.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project) and [MicrosoftExpressionInteractions (For the ActionCommand)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicrosoftExpressionInteractions/1.0.0)
- Event Triggers:

  ```
  <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Text Box 1">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger  EventName="GotFocus">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NotifyFocusedReceivedTxt1Command}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </TextBox>
  ```
- In ViewModel create command NotifyFocusedReceivedTxt1Command

  ```
  public ICommand NotifyFocusedReceivedTxt1Command { get; }

  // in constructor
  this.NotifyFocusedReceivedTxt1Command = new ActionCommand(this.FocusedReceivedTxt1);

  // and method
  private void FocusedReceivedTxt1()
  {
      // Your logic
  }
  ```
- Also,  if you don't want introduce many command/properties you could use same command and pass different textboxes by setting `CommandParameter` (slightly breaks MVVM, but not critically)

  ```
  <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="Text Box 1">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger  EventName="GotFocus">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NotifyFocusedReceivedCommand}" 
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding ., ElementName=textBox1}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </TextBox>

  <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="Text Box 2">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger  EventName="GotFocus">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NotifyFocusedReceivedCommand}" 
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding ., ElementName=textBox2}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </TextBox>
  ```

  and

  ```
  public ICommand NotifyFocusedReceivedCommand { get; }

  // in constructor
  this.NotifyFocusedReceivedCommand = new ActionCommand(this.FocusedReceived);

  // and method
  private void FocusedReceived(object control)
  {
      var txt = (TextBox)control;
      bool isFocused = txt.IsFocused;
      string name = txt.Name;
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm trying to make your first example work for I'm getting an error. This is what I did, 1) Copied your .cs code and created a class `FocusChangedBehavior.cs`. 2) Imported `using System.Windows.Interactivity;` inside the class. 3) Added `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` to my XAML file. 4) Added the interaction behavior to mytextBox`<i:Interaction.Behaviors<local:FocusChangedBehavior IsFocused="{Binding IsFocusedTxt1}" /></i:Interaction.Behaviors>` and here is where I get ERROR: `The type local:FocusChangedBehavior was not found. Verify that you are not...`

Comment: @ lezhkin11-  Any idea what I'm I missing?

Comment: you need to import namespace for the behavior. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE;assembly=ASSEMBLY_WITH_BEHAVIOR"`. If it's same assembly, then you omit assembly attribute. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE"`. It can be any alias name (not just local), in my case it's auto-generated

Comment: Your first example is now working, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsFocused",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(TextBoxProperties),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false,OnIsFocusedChanged)
);

public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject) {
    return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
}

public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value) {
    dependencyObject.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
}
```

**you can use this property**

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how this would be used. Sorry but I'm fairly new to WPF/MVVM/C#.

Comment: What is `OnIsFocusedChanged`?

Answer (score -1):

This can not be done via the ViewModel on Server-side, a workaround would look like this:

**View Code: (js & html)**

```js
function updateFocus(textboxNr) {
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Controller")',
    data: {
      Focus: textboxNr
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
  });
  
}
```

```html
<textarea id="1" name="1" onfocus="updateFocus(1)">Text Box 1</textarea>
<textarea id="2" name="2" onfocus="updateFocus(2)">Text Box 2</textarea>
```

Comment: There is also a way to just attach Event Listeners to a DOM Element and so on, but that is easiest with jquery.

Comment: Another thing, this must be a new controller action that handles the input from the ajax post. And the controller must take a ViewModel as an argument. like: 


public ActionResult Index(MyModel postData) { ... }

Comment: This is a very simple WPF application and I rather not use other languages/technologies. Thanks.

Comment: Ooooooh.... I see... haha I assumed the markup language was html instead of xml

Comment: Well, at lead you know how to achieve this with asp.net mvc