# Frameworks which provide Behavior<T> in .NET Core 3 / WPF

Tags: .net-core-3.0

The [Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v%3Dexpression.40)) class from System.Windows.Interactivity is used in an application I'm working on and this is being ported to .NET Core 3.0 / WPF Desktop.

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for this class, as [System.Windows.Interactivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) is built against the .NET Framework.

Are there any alternatives out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised my question was a bit thick as these packages are **Open Source**...

So I've solved the problem by cloning [microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) and including the source for Behavior and dependencies in my .NET Core 3 application.

Comment: For future readers: There's a nuget package as well https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf as mentioned by @grzegorz-smulko

Answer (score 18):

This answer describes in details what needs to be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240223/532575 .

In short, the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package is a replacement for  `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the .NET Framework version of the WPF Behaviors in your .NET Core 3 project as is - it is 100% compatible (the build warning is ignorable).