# Why is triggers tab missing from MS blend 2019 when i open a WPF .core project, but available for .net projects?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I started using blend 2019 to design my views for WPF projects.
I can't find the triggers tab whenever i open a WPF .core project in blend.

[image]

But when i open a WPF .NET project .. it is there

[image]

why is that ? is there another way for doing triggers in .core different than .NET?

Comment: [Oleg's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project)  was helpful to make it easier to understand that Blend SDK was deprecated and it is now  Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf that is the official package of behaviors. In the same post  [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240223/11518992)   is of great use. But i still don't know why the triggers tab is not there in blend for WPF .core views.

Comment: Blend do not suport .Net Core on Triggers. You can do it by using following code:


<Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown" SourceName="textBlock">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MainWindowAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>