# How to add the reference 'Microsoft.Expression.Interaction' and 'System.Windows.Interactivity' in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c#

How to add the reference 'Microsoft.Expression.Interaction' and 'System.Windows.Interactivity' in visual studio 2019? I saw the Jan's answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56240223/14776331

But when I install the  Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package. I got this error.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the namespace for `xmlns:i` with `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`.