# Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Expression.Drawing" in a WPF solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I attempt to open and build a WPF solution in Visual Studio 2022. However, I get this build error:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Expression.Drawing". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

A similar issue has been posted before regarding `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360209/how-to-add-system-windows-interactivity-to-project/56240223). However, how can I resolve the issue for `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing`? I've installed the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` NuGet package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) NuGet package replaces the [*System.Windows.Interactivity*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff725917(v=expression.40)) types that were shipped as part of Blend. It does **not** provide *Microsoft.Expression.Drawing* types.

The expression blend assemblies are deprecated and not shipped anymore. The *Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET* could be installed until Visual Studio 2017 and found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries
```

You could [download Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/vs/older-downloads/) (Community is sufficient) and install it from there.

The original Blend SDK was still provided by Microsoft for download as standalone about a year or two ago, but now all the [links are dead](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801). Fortunately, there is a snapshot on Wayback Machine where you can reach the [original download](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112015641/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801).

Other than that there are only unofficial sources like these NuGet packages:

- [Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF/)
- [Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend)

If you can, please stick to the original SDK, since unofficial packages may contain *any* code, including malware. They might impose a security risk or contain assemblies not allowed for redistribution.